# NGINX proxy with nodejs on multiple ports

Tags: node.js, nginx, proxy

I have a web application written in Node.js.

This web application listens to multiple ports. For example port `3003` is for sending emails, while another port `4003` is for serving content ... etc.

Now that I'm trying to deploy my application to the server I can connect to the port using the IP `35.190.xx.xx`, so `35.190.xx.xx:3003` does actually send emails and port `35.190.xx.xx:4003` does serve content ... etc.

But those port does not work on the `domain.com`, so neither `domain.com:3003` nor `domain.com:4003` works.

I tried to create a server configuration for those ports with this specific domain in NGINX. But it didn't work.

Is there something I can do? Is it even possible? Keep in mind that I also need to have SSL enabled in the future.

What I have tried (using NGINX):

```
# serving static files
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;
    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index index.html index.htm
    server_name localhost domain.com;
    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }
}

# this causes failed (98: Address already in use) error
# understandable
server {
    listen       3003;
    server_name  domain.com;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3003;
    }
}

# but this also doesn't work!
server {
    listen       3004;
    server_name  domain.com;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3004;
    }
}
```

I'm truly a noob in this subject and would appreciate any help!

Comment: First off, what IP address does your domain point to in DNS?  Does it point to the NGINX server?  Have you configured your domain with a public DNS service to point to your NGINX server's IP address?

Comment: @jfriend00 domain points to the same server IP `35.190.xx.xx` which works on `3003` and `4003` ports. Yes I'm using cloudflare as a DNS.

Comment: This won't work. when you say listen `3004` you can't proxy pass to same port on local. It has to be proxied to another port. So 3004 can proxy to 3003. Else you will have to change your listen to `listen <privateip>:3004;` and in your nodejs make sure it binds to `127.0.0.1:3004`

Comment: did you solve it?